# Get foreign key field from associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, redmine

I want to know field name corresponding to table caption for a given model in Rails.

I am displaying captions using a query model.

> > query.columns.map{|q| q.caption}
> >     => ["Tracker", "Status", "Priority", "Subject", "Assignee", "Target version", "Due date", "% Done"]

Column has names corresponding to captions

> > query.columns.map{|q| q.name}
> >     => [:tracker, :status, :priority, :subject, :assigned_to, :fixed_version, :due_date, :done_ratio]

My model looks like

> > Issue.columns.map{|q| q.name}
> >     => ["id", "tracker_id", "project_id", "subject", "description", "due_date", "category_id", "status_id", "assigned_to_id", "priority_id", "fixed_version_id", "author_id",  "created_on", "updated_on", "start_date", "done_ratio", "estimated_hours", "parent_id"]

I want to get field name(the db field name) corresponding to a caption from the above information.

Sample association in the model

```
belongs_to :assigned_to, :class_name => 'Principal', :foreign_key => 'assigned_to_id'
```

So for above association i want to know the foreign key.

for `assigned_to` i want `'assigned_to_id'`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `reflections` hash holds this kind of information:

```
Issue.reflections['assigned_to'].foreign_key
```

You can also get other information, such as the class (`.active_record`) or the type of association (`.macro`). Prior to rails 4.2, the keys of this hash are symbols and not strings.

Comment: this worked for me...Issue.reflections[:assigned_to].options[:foreign_key].. thanks

Comment: This would only work out if the relation is defined with the active record model and if there is any deviation with the Rails convention of naming the foreign key fields then that should also be specified in the active record model or else it just returns the field name by convention and not the actual field name.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way for Rails 4.2 is:

```
Issue.reflections['assigned_to'].options[:foreign_key]
```

Note that "assigned_to" is a string according to API:

> Returns a Hash of name of the reflection as the key and a
>   AssociationReflection as the value.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflections

Comment: Note: This will return only the custom foreign keys attached to the options hash passed to the association helper. So it will not work in the standard cases where the foreign key is automatically set. BTW Frederick's Solution still works in Rails 4.2

Comment: Indeed! Thank you for noting! Though, to make Frederick's solution work in Rails 4.2, association name must be passed as a string instead of a symbol.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this here in case this helps anyone else. I was trying to get the foreign key from `proxy_association` inside of an association extension.

You can get the `reflection` by simply using `proxy_associtation.reflection`.

Then, using @Frederick Cheung's method above, you can get the foreign_key like so:

```rb
reflection = proxy_association.reflection
reflection.foreign_key
```

You can also get the `class_name` in the same way:

```rb
reflection = proxy_association.reflection
reflection.class_name
```